# Botframework how log history

Tags: history, botframework

Do You have any idea how to log all outgoing/incoming messages? I am not sure how to capture outgoing messages.

I use Chains and Forms.
For example

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, rootDialog.BuildChain);
```

AND

```
activity.CreateReply(.....);
```

Comment: Beyond how every you do this technically, remember to disclose to your users what kind of information you are storing and how they can have it deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I need log complete conversation. Delete conversation is next simple step..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found better solution

```
    public class BotToUserLogger : IBotToUser
{
    private readonly IMessageActivity _toBot;
    private readonly IConnectorClient _client;

    public BotToUserLogger(IMessageActivity toBot, IConnectorClient client)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out _toBot, nameof(toBot), toBot);
        SetField.NotNull(out _client, nameof(client), client);
    }

    public IMessageActivity MakeMessage()
    {
        var toBotActivity = (Activity)_toBot;
        return toBotActivity.CreateReply();
    }

    public async Task PostAsync(IMessageActivity message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await _client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class BotToUserDatabaseWriter : IBotToUser
{
    private readonly IBotToUser _inner;
    public BotToUserDatabaseWriter(IBotToUser inner)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out _inner, nameof(inner), inner);
    }
    public IMessageActivity MakeMessage()
    {
        return _inner.MakeMessage();
    }

    public async Task PostAsync(IMessageActivity message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // loging outgoing message
        Debug.WriteLine(message.Text);

        //TODO log message for example into DB

        await _inner.PostAsync(message, cancellationToken);
    }
```

In controller use

```
 public MessagesController()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<BotToUserLogger>()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Register(c => new BotToUserTextWriter(c.Resolve<BotToUserLogger>()))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.Update(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.Container);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer. Minor fix in the constructor 
`builder.Register(c => new BotToUserTextWriter(c.Resolve<BotToUserLogger>(),Console.Out))`

Comment: How about user to bot messages? Any idea how to register IPostToBot?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like I cant log outgoing message.

I changed SDK source code.

Add event in Conversations.cs

For example like this.

```
  public delegate void MessageSendedEventHandler(object sender, Activity activity, string conversationId);
    public static event MessageSendedEventHandler MessageSended;
```

And add in every Send....HttpMessagesAsync method 
this `MessageSended?.Invoke(this, activity, conversationId);`

its not great solution. But its working